# Removing wrong version of command line tools for XCode

Tags: xcode, macos

by mistake I installed the wrong version of XCode Command Line Tools (CLT) (for XCode 7.3). I installed the right version (7.3.1) and would like to remove not relevant one. But see nothing related in a folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents`. As far as I understand it should be there, but it is not.

From the other hand in `XCode -> Preferences -> Locations` the CLT 7.3.1 is chosen, and there is no other options. Do I understand right that it means that I have only one installation of the CLT and not relevant version was simply overridden?

**The context:**

- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 2):

delete from default library

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

to change default clt

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

[A good article to read](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)